# Ubuntu 15 left mouse click not working

Tags: 15.10, mouse, touchpad

I have a Lenovo X301 that I am donating to a high-school student in need. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 from the ISO off the Ubuntu site and got it up and running but for some reason I can't get any mouse to work using the left click.

I have tried with two separate USB mice as well as the touchpad. Any ideas on how to get left-click functions restored?

Comment: The mouse was working during installation and you've tried several usb ports I take it?? I've checked and there are several possible reasons why your mouse stopped working. Apparently some people reported that the mouse started working again by opening a virtual console <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and returning to the x server <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. You can try that. Some other suggestions are to switch to the left handed configuration and check if that works or even disabling the mouse in the BIOS, boot and re-enabling it. you can also try reinstalling.

Comment: Yes, it did work during install, I did test other usb ports and I did switch right and left click.  I tried multiple mice.  Disabling touchpad mouse didn't help.  I'll just reinstall and see if that fixes things.

Comment: that's probably the easiest course of action to take.

Comment: I am not sure what to make of this.  I had the same issue again. I tried 15.10 and had left click functions at setup.  Once I got to the wifi connection left click stopped. I have multiple known good mice and none of them work. I tried also with 14 LTS and have the same experience. Mouse function stops working once I get to the wifi connection in setup.

Comment: hmm, it sounds as though your system detects the input but has it mapped incorrectly. let's do a quick test: run `xinput list` in a terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and note the id corresponding to your mouse. Run `xinput test <id>` where <id> is the id of your mouse. Can you check if it notices a button press when you click your left mouse button? If it does return something can you post what?

Comment: you can also test this by holding down the left mouse button and running `xinput query-state <id>`

Comment: So it doesn't notice the left button on the touch pad with any of the tests but it does notice the left button on the usb mouse. I have done some more testing and I suspect the left mouse on the touchpad is failing. When I tried reinstalling again it detected the left touch but then navigating deeper into the install menu it failed and caused all left-clicking for any mouse to fail.

Comment: oke, so what button id does your usb mouse show?? your fix could be as easy as re-assigning the buttons

Comment: The USB Mouse is id=9 and the Synaptic Touchpad is id=12. If I disable the Synaptics from BIOS then everything starts to work fine. I think that will just have to be "good enough" for this laptop.

Comment: Yay, not much you can do against broken hardware. (and I meant the left mouse button press id but ooh well, it works now). pretty wierd bug though

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the computer receives the mouse click (as a diagnostic check) by running the following commands:

`xinput list` (note the id corresponding to your mouse)
`xinput test <id>` (where  is the id of your mouse)

for further info check the comments to the question